# Add padding on a background picture

Tags: html, css

Please help me someone with this code.

CSS Code

```
    #nav, #nav ul
            {
                width:1000px;
                background-color: #F3F3F3;
                margin: 0 auto;

            }


     #nav li
        {
            float: left;
            padding-top:3px;
            height:20px;
            text-align:left;
            text-transform:uppercase; 
            position: relative; 
            display: block;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align: left;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding:10px 15px 0 15px;
            background:url(../image/border.png) no-repeat right center;
        }
```

And I have problem with

```
#nav li:hover
    {   

        background: #3EBBEC url(../image/arrow.png) no-repeat left; 
        color: #FFFFFF;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

HTML code

```
<html>
<head>Test Page</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li id="nav">test1</li>
<li id="nav">test2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The total code below. Here I need to remove space before text and the image "Arrow". How will I be able to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this CSS and see what happens

```
#nav li:hover
    {   

        background: url("../image/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 4px 10px #3EBBEC; 
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.nav li{
   padding-left: 20px;
}
```

I just realized that your current css is not correct, that wouldnt take effect on your html.
You should use:

```
li.nav{
   padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I see that you edited your question. You're CSS wont work. check my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/killerbytes/YGVkp/)

Comment: yes @killbytes you really made it almost. But just tell me how can I reduce the gap between the red arrow and the text. I want the red arrow will appear just beside the text and there will be no gapping between them. left center attribute putting the image into corner what is the main issue which I don't want

Comment: just adjust the padding-left. On your css you are using     padding:10px 15px 0 15px; the last value is the padding-left

Comment: I have tried that but I am not getting the expected result. The arrow is staying away from the text

Comment: then reduce the left padding, try 5px

Answer (score 0):

to remove the image you have to delete this line

```
background:url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
```

about the space you need to do this :

```
li {float:right; display:block;}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove image. The Background image is placing on the corner left. I want some specing where the image can fit just before either "test1" or "test2". I have tried everything but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

This code below ll never work....

```
.nav li
{
  padding:0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav li:hover
{
  background:url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
  text-align:center;
  margin 0 auto;

}
```

use,

```
li.nav
{
  padding:0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li.nav:hover
{
  background:url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the ul element also has default styling try adding this if you want to remove all the space

```
ul{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
li.nav{
  padding:0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li.nav:hover{
  background:url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

you also might want this:

```
ul{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style-type: none;
}
```